# netlify serverless function 502 error POST request

Tags: function, api, build, serverless, netlify

```
const { OpenAIApi, Configuration } = require("openai");
//
// Set up OpenAI configuration
const openaiConfig = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
//
// Create OpenAI instance
const openai = new OpenAIApi(openaiConfig);

// Docs on event and context
const handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const { httpMethod, body } = event;

    if (httpMethod === "GET") {
      console.log("welcome")
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Welcome to the API server" }),
      };
    }

    if (httpMethod === "OPTIONS") {
      // Handle preflight request
      return {
        statusCode: 204, // No content
      };
    }

    if (httpMethod === "POST") {
      const { path } = event;
      console.log(path);

      try {
        if (path === "/bot-reply") {
          const { outline } = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(outline);
          const responseHeaders = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          };
          const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: `Generate a short message.\n###\noutline: ${outline}\nmessage:\n`,
            max_tokens: 60,
          });
          const botReply = response.data.choices[0].text.trim();
          return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: responseHeaders,
            body: JSON.stringify({ botReply }),
          };
        }

        if (path === "/synopsis") {
          const { outline } = JSON.parse(body);
          const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: `Generate an engaging, funny joke.\n###\noutline: ${outline}\nsynopsis:\n`,
            max_tokens: 700,
          });
          const synopsis = response.data.choices[0].text.trim();
          return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ synopsis }) };
        }

        if (path === "/title") {
          const { synopsis } = JSON.parse(body);
          const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: `Generate a catchy melody: ${synopsis}`,
            max_tokens: 25,
            temperature: 0.6,
          });
          const title = response.data.choices[0].text.trim();
          return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ title }) };
        }

        if (path === "/stars") {
          const { synopsis } = JSON.parse(body);
          const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: `Extract the elements in brackets from our ${synopsis}.\n###\nsynopsis: ${synopsis}\nnames:\n`,
            max_tokens: 30,
          });
          const stars = response.data.choices[0].text.trim();
          return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ stars }) };
        }

        if (path === "/image-prompt") {
          const { title, synopsis } = JSON.parse(body);
          const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: `Give a short description.\n###\ntitle: ${title}\nsynopsis: ${synopsis}\nimage description:\n`,
            temperature: 0.8,
            max_tokens: 100,
          });
          const imagePrompt = response.data.choices[0].text.trim();
          return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ imagePrompt }) };
        }

        if (path === "/image-url") {
          const { imagePrompt } = JSON.parse(body);
          const response = await openai.createImage({
            prompt: `${imagePrompt}. There should be no text in this image.`,
            n: 1,
            size: "512x512",
            response_format: "url",
          });
          const imageUrl = response.data.data[0].url;
          return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ imageUrl }) };
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        return {
          statusCode: 500,
          body: JSON.stringify({ error: "An error occurred" }),
        };
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return { statusCode: 500, body: error.toString() };
  }
};

module.exports = { handler };
```

I am encountering an issue with the POST requests in your Netlify serverless function.

no matter how I try GET request is working fine but POST requests somewhat I got error, It was working fine when I try seperately on local server and client. However when I deployed to the netlify serverless function to the netlify servers.

I appraciate if any one solve this